# Azure Mobile Services: connect client app to local web project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, local, azure-mobile-services

The documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn629482.aspx

demonstrates how to add a new Azure Mobile Services project locally to Visual Studio 2013 which you can then publish.

It then demonstrates how you can connect your client app to that published service.

My question is: are you able to connect the client app to the LOCAL service I just added? I'd rather test everything locally than have to push out a publish everything something changes, which is bound to happen a lot during this early stage.

If this is possible how is it done? a link to a doc on this would be great but so far I've not been successful in finding one. thanks

Comment: I just scanned the article you posted and very quickly found the section titled 'Test the mobile service by running it on the local machine'.  Did that section not have the information you needed?

Comment: thanks for the reply! while this will allow me to test the service by running it and issuing http requests, what I do not know is how to actually connect my mobile app itself to this local service so that the app can call it instead of the published azure site. the azure site provides a url and api key, but I don't know how to find the same thing for local...

Comment: The local service does not require any authentication, so you can create the client object without passing a key to its constructor.

Comment: hey you're right, thanks! can you post this as an answer so I can give you credit? also, is it possible to add the "identity" features so that I could also test facebook login locally or would that have to remain on the cloud? thanks again!